# Reactive Programming: How to subscribe and sample an event emitter?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rxjs, eventemitter

I'm suscribing to an event emitter in a React Native application that is consuming [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager).

```
handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic(data) {

    console.log('Received data from ' + data.peripheral + ' characteristic ' + data.characteristic, data.value);

  }
bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );
```

I'm dealing with a Bluetooth event Stream which frequency is either 50, 100 or 200 events per second (Hz).

I'm interrested in all events at 50 Hz, half of them at 100 Hz and a quarter of them at 200 Hz.
What is the correct way to subscribe to this event Stream with RxJS and which operator should I use to sample the data?

I may be wrong but I can't seem to find a helper method to create an observable from an event emitter.

Comment: what do you mean by interested in half of them and quarter of them ?

Comment: I think he meant every 2nd/4th event..

Comment: I mean, at 100Hz, take 1 event drop the next one and so on. At 200 Hz take 1 event, drop the next 3 events and so on.

Comment: ..which results in exactly what I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fromEventPattern`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern) should be what you're looking for.

It lets you create an observable based on custom event emissions (like what you've got with this BLE manager).

I've provided a snippet below outlining how you might use it.

Notice the `scan()` and `filter()` combination. By using the former operator to keep track of the n<sup>th</sup> event, it effectively changes the rate at which events are sampled and thus handled by any subscribers.

In your scenario, you'll want the `scan()` to also keep track of the event emitted, so you can eventually `map()` it after the `filter()` call, so subscribers will receive it. The key point here is to keep track of event state within the `scan()` (i.e. tick and event data properties, `t` and `data` in the snippet respectively) as you accumulate events.

```js
const { fromEventPattern } = rxjs;
const { filter, map, scan } = rxjs.operators;

// Tweak parameters to vary demo
const hz = 200;
const sample = 4;

function addEmitterHandler(handler) {
  // bleManagerEmitter.addListener('event', handler)
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    handler({ timestamp: Date.now() });
  }, 1000 / hz);
  return intervalId;
}

function removeEmitterHandler(handler, intervalId) {
  // bleManagerEmitter.removeListener(...)
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

// Simulate emissions using the `setInterval()` call
const emitter = fromEventPattern(
  addEmitterHandler,
  removeEmitterHandler
);

emitter.pipe(
  // Use `scan()` and `filter()` combination to adjust sampling
  scan((state, data) => {
    const t = (state.t % (sample + 1)) + 1;
    return { t, data };
  }, { t: 0, data: null }),
  filter(state => state.t % sample === 0),
  // Use `map()` to forward event data only
  map(state => state.data),
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your sample, how do I get the event data that is sent to handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic in the first place?

Comment: @OlivierMATROT, although I had already hinted at this in my original answer, I've updated my snippet to be more explicit about how you might go about passing through the event data. For demonstration, I've wired up the handler to now call with a single data argument containing a timestamp. Take note at how the `scan()` now keeps track of both the tick (to control sampling) and the event data to forward through.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll accept your answer as soon as I've tested my new code

Comment: I'd say the snippet has become invalid because I can't run it.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT, in that case you must be using an old browser without support for ES2015 features (i.e. for `const`, destructuring). It should just run with the "Run code snippet" button. Anyway, that's beside the point. My snippet isn't supposed to be a verbatim solution for what you're trying to do. I've addressed the question asked by showing: 1) how to subscribe to a custom event emitter and, 2) how to sample every fixed number of events from the stream.